# Grep phone numbers that can be formatted in different ways

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I have a file with lines and some of the lines include phone numbers, which all have 10 numbers, but are formatted differently from one another. Examples:

```
00 00 00 00 00
00.00.00.00.00
00000-00000
0-0000-00000
(000)000-0000
```

I need to find only the lines with phone numbers and print those. To get even more confusing, there are lines with [IP adresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) which shouldn't be printed :(
How do I do that?

Comment: start by referencing all the possible formats. Then you can either try to find 1 regex that covers it all, or search for every individual format.

Comment: You mean US only phone numbers or any?

Comment: @jm666 I had US and french numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
egrep '([0-9].*){10}' file.txt | egrep -v '(^|[ \t])[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}([ \t]|$)'
```

The first regex looks for lines with 10 digits in them, ignoring all other characters. The second regex filters out IP addresses. Both of these regexes are crude, but the basic idea is there. Tweak them as needed.

(The first one, for instance, will allow any characters in between the digits; you might want to allow only certain symbols and whitespace. The second will filter out things that look like IP addresses but are invalid, like `300.400.50.60`.)

Comment: possibly the `(` in the last format is a character that we want to capture too

Comment: @njzk2 This will print the whole line, not just the matching parts.

Answer (score 1):

This example will only print the matching part of each line containing a phone number. It trades performance for readability as it greps through all the filters for each line:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    while read filter
    do
        egrep -o "$filter" <<<"$line"
    done <<FILTERS
([0-9]{2}[ \.]){4}[0-9]{2}
[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{5}
[0-9]-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5}
[\(][0-9]{3}[\)][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}
FILTERS

done < "$1"
```

This example will still be quite readable, but does not show the performance shortcomings of the first one:

```
FILTERS="
([0-9]{2}[ \.]){4}[0-9]{2}
[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{5}
[0-9]-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5}
[\(][0-9]{3}[\)][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}
"
# replace newlines with '|',
FILTERS=$( tr "
" "|" <<<"$FILTERS" )
# surround result with '(' and ')':
FILTERS="(""$FILTERS"")"

while read line
do
        egrep -o "$FILTERS" <<<"$line"
done < "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

With the right perl module - US only phone numbers:

```
perl -MNumber::Phone -nlE 'say $_ if Number::Phone->new('US', $_)'
```

From the next input

```
00 00 00 00 00
00.00.00.00.00
00000-00000
0-0000-00000
(000)000-0000
(320)234-4565
32023-44565
12042345678
2042345678
1(201)2345678
201-23-45-678
+421-934-4354
1 242 555 0199
1 246 555 0199
1 264 555 0199
1 268 555 0199
1 284 555 0199
1 340 555 0199
1 345 555 0199
1 441 555 0199
1 473 555 0199
1 649 555 0199
+441234567890
```

prints

```
(320)234-4565
32023-44565
2042345678
201-23-45-678
```

The next code:

```
perl -MNumber::Phone::Country -nlE 'say "$_:\t",phone2country($_)'
```

prints:

```
00 00 00 00 00: NANP
00.00.00.00.00: NANP
00000-00000:    NANP
0-0000-00000:   NANP
(000)000-0000:  NANP
(320)234-4565:  US
32023-44565:    US
12042345678:    CA
2042345678: CA
1(201)2345678:  US
201-23-45-678:  US
+421-934-4354:  SK
1 242 555 0199: BS
1 246 555 0199: BB
1 264 555 0199: AI
1 268 555 0199: AG
1 284 555 0199: VG
1 340 555 0199: VI
1 345 555 0199: KY
1 441 555 0199: BM
1 473 555 0199: GD
1 649 555 0199: TC
+441234567890:  GB
```